# Switches 'HPE OfficeConnect 1920S' - Enable SSH / TFTP Services

Tags: switch, hp, ssh, tftp

We need to manage switches HPE OfficeConnect 1920S remotely but only HTTP/HTTPS Administration is available.

HPE 1920S has an special operating system, neither Procurve nor Comware. We are looking for technical documentation which describes how to enable SSH/TFTP services but we have not found anything yet.

Do you know how we could enable SSH/TFTP services in HPE 1920S switches?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the switch can't be managed through SSH. The [specification page](https://www.hpe.com/us/en/product-catalog/networking/networking-switches/pip.specifications.1900-switch-products.7399514.html) mention a "Limited command-line interface" and the [quickspec](https://h20195.www2.hpe.com/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=c04394247) mention "ACLs provide Telnet and SNMP access" but doesn't mention SSH except in the context of SFTP (to manage image / config files)

Comment: I tried to edit and upload the **startup-config** but with no success. When I upload it, as well to backup-startup, reboot the switch, it stays in Backup config but in startup its without those added parameters. I am using PD 2.06. So I am not able to enable Telnet, because it doesn´t stay in the startup. Even that function "Copy from to doesnt work".

Answer (score 3):

Well, actually you CAN enable telnet and ssh. It's completely unsupported, but anyway:

1. Update firmware to latest version, I used PD.02.06.stk.
2. Go to Maintenance ->  Backup and Update Manage, click download and select startup-config. Download that file.
3. Edit startup-config file (it's a text file, use any text editor), insert "ip telnet server enable" before config statement, like this:

```
!Current Configuration:
!
!System Description "HPE OfficeConnect Switch 1920S 24G 2SFP PoE+ (370W) JL385A, PD.02.06, Linux 3.6.5-a07f8920, U-Boot 2012.10-00118-g3773021 (Oct 11 2016 - 15:39:54)"
!System Software Version "PD.02.06"
!System Up Time          "0 days 0 hrs 6 mins 3 secs"
!Additional Packages     HPE QOS,HPE IPv6 Management,HPE Routing
!Current SNTP Synchronized Time: SNTP Last Attempt Status Is Not Successful
!
network protocol none
network parms 10.1.1.50 255.255.255.0 10.1.1.1
vlan database
exit
ip telnet server enable
configure
sntp client mode unicast
sntp server "10.1.1.1"
```

4. Upload startup-config file as startup config
5. Reboot switch and telnet to switch ip
6. Login and enable ssh:

```
enable
configure
crypto key generate rsa
crypto key generate dsa
exit
ip ssh server enable
ip ssh protocol 2
write memory confirm
quit
```

Here is original thread: https://community.hpe.com/t5/Web-and-Unmanaged/How-to-Enable-Telnet-and-SSH-on-HPE-1920s-OfficeConnect/td-p/6988775 , today I enabled telnet on my 1920S using this trick.

Answer (score 2):

18xx and 19xx are "smart-managed" or web-managed only, no telnet, no SSH. Some 1920s have a minimal serial/USB console though. The switch has TFTP and SFTP clients but no server.

I've looked into 1810 switches a while ago (how to automate config backups using `curl`). These SOHO switches apparently use firmware made by the chipset manufacturer that has been branded by HP. 1810v1 and 1810v2 differ significantly by site structure and backup file format, so that they're actually two different devices.

Depending on what you're trying to do, you might be able to accomplish some automated management using `curl`, but if you want a real console interface you'll need to replace the switch.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that suggested solution (inserting "ip telnet server enable" into startup-config file and then enabling ssh) works only till firmware version PD.02.06.stk (including).

When upgrading to newer firmware it seems that telnet and ssh servers have been removed and the suggested solution does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

See the following link: https://glazenbakje.wordpress.com/2012/08/21/hp-v1910-secret-commando-list-how-to-enable-it/

Both the V1910 and the (old) 1920 have a technician's CLI, which is completely unsupported, but works good enough. Keep in mind that this is not about the 1920S. I just ordered a demo model of the 1920S and will get it on monday. Will test if the CLI is accessible then.

Comment: Some weeks ago, I opened a Support Case and HPE Networking told me SSH service is not available on switches 1920S. Anyway, as I suppose the firmware is based on Linux, I guess there must be a non-official method to active SSH. Let me know about your testing results.

Comment: So I got the 1920S and have found no way to connect successfully to SSH. The webinterface does not show any option and SSH connections are actively being closed immediately. There is also no console port, so I guess that a non-official method would require opening the switch.